# Proving the least upper bound property for closed intervals in $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

for example, given $\mathbb{R}$ has the least upper bound property, is there a trivial way to show that $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ has the least upper bound property?

Trivial as in relatively straightforward, unlike the construction of $\mathbb{R}$ to get that it has the least upper bound property.

Comment: A closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ definitely has the least upper bound property, this follows from $\mathbb{R}$ having that property.

Comment: How would I state that in a proof? @Mark

Comment: Just try it by using the definitions. If you don't know what a closed set is, try to prove it for the interval $[a,b]$ that you asked about. Take a nonempty, bounded subset. Why must it have a least upper bound?

Answer (score 1):

If $S\subseteq[a,b]$ is nonempty, then it is bounded above in $\mathbb R$ (by $b$), and so it has a least upper bound in $\mathbb R$. Thus, all we need to show is that $\sup S\in[a,b]$. This is trivial once you remember the definition of the supremum.

Since $\sup S$ is an upper bound of $S$, we have $\sup S\ge a$. In more detail: by hypothesis, $S$ contains an element $x_0$, and since $S\subseteq[a,b]$, we have $\sup S\ge x_0\ge a$.

Since $\sup S$ is the *least* upper bound of $S$, it is smaller than any other upper bound of $S$. As $b$ is an upper bound of $S$, we have $\sup S\le b$. Hence, $\sup S\in[a,b]$, and we're done.